# bluetooth keyboard needs to pair after each startup

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, asus

I am running ubuntu 18.04.02 on an asus t100 chi. I am having issues with the Bluetooth docking keyboard. It will pair successfully, however when I restart the device it will not automatically reconnect, and I will have to par the keyboard again. I have tired pairing both through the gui, and using bluetoothctl, with both having the same result.

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ sudo systemctl is-enabled bluetooth.service
enabled
```

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep -i -E 'DiscoverableTimeout|AutoEnable'
#DiscoverableTimeout = 0
# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
AutoEnable=true
```

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ sudo lshw | grep -i -A6 "description: Bluetooth wireless"
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    4.817241] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.817279] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.817286] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.817290] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.817302] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.885323] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    4.885327] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    4.885328] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    4.885355] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    4.885357] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    4.885377] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    4.885484] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    4.893148] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    4.893175] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    4.893177] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    4.893178] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    5.109925] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 84
[    5.110418] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x0f
[    5.111559] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4324B3
[    5.111565] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4324B3 (002.004.006) build 0000
[    5.125425] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4324B3.hcd failed with error -2
[    5.125434] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4324B3.hcd not found
[    6.997822] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.997825] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.997832] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  132.062973] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  132.062994] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  132.063007] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  152.038254] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[  152.038265] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[  152.092534] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:0B05:8502.0002/input/input15
[  152.094473] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:0B05:8502.0002/input/input16
[  152.095907] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:0B05:8502.0002/input/input19
[  152.096720] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:0B05:8502.0002/input/input21
[  152.097803] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:0B05:8502.0002/input/input22
[  152.098487] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:0B05:8502.0002/input/input23
[  152.100019] asus 0005:0B05:8502.0002: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [ASUS T100CHI DOCKING] on 31:4a:9f:ef:37:28
[ 1367.471899] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0003/input/input24
[ 1367.476591] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0003/input/input25
[ 1367.477031] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0003/input/input28
[ 1367.477312] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0003/input/input30
[ 1367.477707] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0003/input/input31
[ 1367.477958] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0003/input/input32
[ 1367.478246] asus 0005:0B05:8502.0003: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [ASUS T100CHI DOCKING] on 31:4a:9f:ef:37:28
[21423.816536] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0004/input/input33
[21423.817044] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0004/input/input34
[21423.817212] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0004/input/input37
[21423.817376] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0004/input/input39
[21423.817663] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0004/input/input40
[21423.817900] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0004/input/input41
[21423.818093] asus 0005:0B05:8502.0004: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [ASUS T100CHI DOCKING] on 31:4a:9f:ef:37:28
[23103.831370] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0005/input/input42
[23103.832245] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0005/input/input43
[23103.835537] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0005/input/input46
[23103.835923] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0005/input/input48
[23103.836320] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0005/input/input49
[23103.836552] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0005/input/input50
[23103.836972] asus 0005:0B05:8502.0005: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [ASUS T100CHI DOCKING] on 31:4a:9f:ef:37:28
[26809.570655] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0006/input/input51
[26809.571154] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0006/input/input52
[26809.571292] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0006/input/input55
[26809.571434] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0006/input/input57
[26809.571663] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0006/input/input58
[26809.571812] input: ASUS T100CHI DOCKING as /devices/platform/80860F0A:00/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:0B05:8502.0006/input/input59
[26809.571981] asus 0005:0B05:8502.0006: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [ASUS T100CHI DOCKING] on 31:4a:9f:ef:37:28
```

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ grep load-module /etc/pulse/default.pa | sort
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
load-module module-always-sink
load-module module-augment-properties
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
load-module module-card-restore
load-module module-console-kit
load-module module-default-device-restore
load-module module-detect
load-module module-device-restore
#load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
load-module module-esound-protocol-unix
load-module module-filter-apply
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-gconf
load-module module-intended-roles
load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=2
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp format=s16be channels=2 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='RTP Multicast Sink'"
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-pipe-sink
load-module module-position-event-sounds
load-module module-rescue-streams
load-module module-role-cork
#load-module module-rtp-recv
#load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
load-module module-switch-on-connect
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
load-module module-systemd-login
load-module module-udev-detect
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ pulseaudio --kill
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory
```

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ pulseaudio --start
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ pulseaudio --check -v
I: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Failed to open /proc/4608/stat: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon not running
```

```
josh@josh-T100CHI:~$ ls -l /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4324B3.hcd
ls: cannot access '/lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4324B3.hcd': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post output of the following commands: 1. `sudo systemctl is-enabled bluetooth.service` 2. `cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep -i -E 'DiscoverableTimeout|AutoEnable'` 3. `sudo lshw | grep -i -A6 "description: Bluetooth wireless"` 4. `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` 5. `grep load-module /etc/pulse/default.pa | sort` 6. `rfkill` and 7. `pulseaudio --check -v`. Thanks

Comment: I have added the results you were looking for. Thank you for helping with this.

Comment: Audio Daemon is not  running. Please start up Audio Daemon by commands `pulseaudio --kill` and `pulseaudio --start`. Please verify the status with `pulseaudio --check -v`. Please report. Thanks.

Comment: Command `dmesg` displays that **bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4324B3.hcd failed with error -2** which should also be resolved. Please post the output of the command `ls -l /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4324B3.hcd`. Thanks.

Comment: Many laptop computers have a hardware switch or key combination to turn Bluetooth on and off. Look for a switch on your computer or a key on your keyboard. The keyboard key is often accessed with the help of the `Fn` key.

Comment: There is no switch for bluetooth on this machine. any fn keys are on the bluetooth keyboard itself, which is the one I'm having issues with. I have added the results you requested.

Comment: You must reinstall `Pulse Audio`. Issue commands `sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio` and `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove`. Then **reboot** the computer. Remove the following folders: `rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse`. Now install with command: `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`, `sudo alsa force-reload` and `pavucontrol`.  Issue the command the check the status of pulseaudio `pulseaudio --check -v`, and also post the output of this command. Thanks.